# No audio element associated

Tags: javascript, audio

I´m doing the Wes Bos 30 days challenge and the first one the drum kit when I press the key down, always says null like the audio was not associated, but it is. Am I missing something really obvious? The path is correct and the file is a wav that works.

```
<div class="keys">
  <div data-key="65" class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="83" class="key">
  <kbd>S</kbd>
  <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="68" class="key">
  <kbd>D</kbd>
  <span class="sound">Kick</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="70" class="key">
  <kbd>F</kbd>
  <span class="sound">openhat"</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="71" class="key">
  <kbd>G</kbd>
  <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="72" class="key">
  <kbd>H</kbd>
  <span class="sound">ride</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="74" class="key">
  <kbd>J</kbd>
  <span class="sound">snare</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="75" class="key">
  <kbd>K</kbd>
  <span class="sound">tom</span>
  </div>
   <div data-key="76" class="key">
  <kbd>L</kbd>
  <span class="sound">tink</span>
  </div>
</div>

<audio data-key="65" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="Sounds/bass_guitar1.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="72" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="74" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="75" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="76" src="Sounds/banjo.wav"></audio>
```

Js

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
    console.log(audio);


});
```

Comment: Do the keycodes match?

Comment: Are you using apostrophes or back ticks for the query selector? `'audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]'` is one string, but `\`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]\`` will correctly put in the `e.keyCode` value into the string.

Comment: @Alex Good catch.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @Alex good one. It was really that:) thanks